# Referencing another equation with tweaked tag

Tags: cross-referencing, align, tags

Suppose I have a tagged equation defined in an `align` environment, labelled using command `\label`.

Now I write another equation, but I want it tagged with the same number as the first equation plus a bespoke suffix, e.g. if the first equation is tagged (12), I want the second one tagged (12-2) or (12-b). I also want the suffixed tag to display as such if I reference the equation.

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may achieve your objective by using `\tag` -- a macro provide by the `amsmath` package, i.e., the same package that provides the `align` environment -- to override the default appearance of the "number" associated with an equation. The argument of `\tag` may contain a `\ref` statement that points to another equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\tag" and "\eqref" macros and "align" env.
\setlength{\textwidth}{3in} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{11}   % just for this example

\begin{align} 
a^2+b^2&=c^2 \label{pyth} \\
0+0&=0 \tag{\ref{pyth}-2} \label{triv} 
\end{align}
A cross-reference to equation \eqref{triv}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you this works. It has a minor drawback though: the suffixed equation tag appears as an hyperref to the first equation. Is there a way to override that behavior?

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw - Just change `\tag{\ref{pyth}-2}` to `\tag{\ref*{pyth}-2}`. Note: `\ref*` is a command provided by the `hyperref` package, so it won't work *unless* the `hyperref` package is loaded.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!